# List all files and folder in google drive

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now. I hope I can get some guidance on this. The purpose of the following script is to get a full list of folders and files with subfolders and their files included.

Here is what I currently have:

```
  var counter = 0

  var files = folder.getFiles();  
  var subfolders = folder.getFolders();
  var folderPath = folder.getName();

  while (subfolders.hasNext()){   
    subfolder = subfolders.next(); 
    var row = [];
    //row.push(subfolder.getName(),'',subfolder.getId(),subfolder.getUrl(),subfolder.getSize(),subfolder.getDateCreated(),subfolder.getLastUpdated());
    //list.push(row); 
    if(counter > 0){
      var files = subfolder.getFiles();
    }

    while (files.hasNext()){
      file = files.next();
      var vals = file.getUrl();
      var row = [];
      if(counter == 0){
        row.push(folder.getName(),file.getName(),file.getId(),file.getUrl(),file.getSize(),file.getDateCreated(),file.getLastUpdated())
      }else{
        row.push(folderPath + '/' + subfolder.getName(),file.getName(),file.getId(),file.getUrl(),file.getSize(),file.getDateCreated(),file.getLastUpdated())        
      }
      list.push(row);    
    }
    counter = counter + 1
  }
```

It currently gets the folder names and file names for the current folder and it's subfolder. It doesn't go any further than that. I'm stuck trying to figure out how to get a loop going to continue until there are no more sub-folders.

It isn't a very big drive. There are less than 10 levels but would like the flexibility to go further if needed.

Comment: For example, is this library useful for your situation? https://github.com/tanaikech/FilesApp

Comment: This looks like it might be helpful: https://alicekeeler.com/2020/05/05/google-drive-list-the-files/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Recursion](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/recursion-in-javascript-1608032c7a1f) is beneficial in this case. The code below calls the recursive method `recurseFolder()` which takes a Folder and Array as a parameter. It adds all the files in the folder to a list, then calls itself on any subfolders it finds.

```
function test(){
  var root = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var list = [];

  var list = recurseFolder(root, list);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(list));

  //This is just how I am testing the outputed list. You can do what you need.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  list.forEach(function (row){
   sheet.appendRow(row); 
  });
}

function recurseFolder(folder, list){
  var files = folder.getFiles();  
  var subfolders = folder.getFolders();

  while (files.hasNext()){ //add all the files to our list first.
    var file = files.next();
    var row = [];
    Logger.log("File: " + folder.getName());
    row.push(folder.getName(),file.getName(),file.getId(),file.getUrl(),file.getSize(),file.getDateCreated(),file.getLastUpdated())
    list.push(row);
  }


  while (subfolders.hasNext()){   //Recurse through child folders.
    subfolder = subfolders.next(); 
    Logger.log("Folder: " + subfolder.getName());
    list = recurseFolder(subfolder, list); //Past the original list in so it stays a 2D Array suitible for inserting into a range.
  }

  return list;
}
```

I'm not sure if the output is formatted how you intended so you might need to play with it a little. *Note: It will easily time out if run on a larger Drive.*

Comment: I'm getting an error when i run this. It says `The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 14 but the range has 7. (line 40, file "Code")`. Why is it 14?

Comment: This error doesn't have anything to do with the code I posted. Are you trying to insert the list into a spreadsheet after?

Comment: yes. This is the code for that. `detailsSht.getRange(1,1,list.length,list[0].length).setValues(list);`

Comment: Okay, right now it's creating arrays within arrays, it'll have to be modified to fit into a spreadsheet nicely. I can help with that in a bit

Comment: Alright. I'm trying my best to merge what you have with what I have. I'll have to do some more research on arrays within arrays.

Comment: I've updated my code so it returns a 2D array suitable for a Spreadsheet instead of a nested one. I'm still not sure what output you are expecting as far as the parent folder names, but let me know how this works.

Comment: That did it. I'm going to modify it a little for my needs but the output is very close to what I needed. Thanks. I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: Any way to get folder path rather than the immediate folder it is in?

Comment: it is cool snippet, thank you! 
but, why it skipps folders without files?

Comment: @Psychozoic that's because it only adds an entry to the array when it finds a file. 'row.push(...);'.

Answer (score 0):

You need a function that will navigate the folder structure recursively, meaning that if it runs into a subfolder within a folder, it will call itself again passing that folder as a new parent.

function listFolders(parentFolderId) {

```
var sourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderId) || DriveApp.getRootFolder();

  var folders = sourceFolder.getFolders();

  var files = sourceFolder.getFiles();

  while (files.hasNext()) {

    var file = files.next();              
    //Do something
  }

  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();         
    listFolders(folder.getId());

  }

}
```

Note that this function will still time out if you have lots of files in your Drive, in which case you need to store the state of your app using PropertiesService and schedule the function to run again using triggers via the ScriptApp. You can achieve this by saving the continuation token for your Files Iterator between script executions
[More on ContinuationToken](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator#getcontinuationtoken)