# apps script, get files in folder

Tags: google-apps-script

Getting file list in specific folder but I keep getting error saying 
TypeError: DriveApp.getFolder is not a function (line 2, file "Code")

any help is greatly appreciated

```
function listFilesInFolder() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolder("Folder-Name");
  var contents = folder.getFiles();

  var file;
  var data;

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.clear();

  sheet.appendRow(["Name", "URL", "ID"]);

  for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
    file = contents[i];

    if (file.getFileType() == "SPREADSHEET") {
      continue;
    }

    data = [ 
      file.getName(),
      file.getUrl(),
      file.getId(),
    ];

    sheet.appendRow(data);
  }
};
```

Comment: The reason of your error message is `getFolder` of `DriveApp.getFolder("Folder-Name")`. When you want to retrieve the folder object using the folder name, please use `getFoldersByName(name)`. And this returns FolderIterator. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfoldersbynamename) Also, `getFiles()` returns FileIterator. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfiles) Please be careful them. I think that this thread might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/q/54912207/7108653

Answer (score 0):

The reason of your error message is `getFolder` of `DriveApp.getFolder("Folder-Name")`, this method doesn't exist.

When you want to retrieve the folder object using the folder name, please use `getFoldersByName(name)`. And this returns `FolderIterator`. Also, `getFiles()` returns `FileIterator`.

This thread might be useful: stackoverflow.com/q/54912207/7108653

### Reference

[getFoldersByName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfoldersbynamename)

[getFiles](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfiles)

– Tanaike