# Automatically delete files from specific folder

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm just wondering is there any way to made this script (https://www.cirriustech.co.uk/blog/how-to-auto-tidy-files-in-google-drive/) working on specific folder in my drive.

I have a project made using google forms and sheets, in google forms there is an upload form which the files saved to specific folder. My master folder (the project) has sub-folders, one of them is where the files stored. I need a script that will delete files in this folder in a certain period.

I've tried to find any scripts that will worked that way, and i feel the link above is just getting closer to what i need. Any help or different scripts that work will help me a lot.

Add: this is the code

```js
function GetFilesByDate() {
  var arrFileIDs = [];

  var Threshold = new Date().getTime()-3600*1000*24*7;
    // 30 is the number of days 
    //(3600 seconds = 1 hour, 1000 milliseconds = 1 second, 24 hours = 1 day and 30 days is the duration you wanted
    //needed in yr-month-day format

  var CullDate = new Date(Threshold);
  var strCullDate = Utilities.formatDate(CullDate, "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
  console.info(strCullDate);

  var FileID = "";
  var FileName = "";

  //Create an array of file ID's by date criteria
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(
     'modifiedDate < "' + strCullDate + '"');

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var FileID = file.getId();
    var FileName = file.getName();

    if (FileName.indexOf('.mp4') > -1 ) {
    arrFileIDs.push(FileID);
    console.info('FileID: ' + FileID);
    console.info('Last Updated: ' + file.getLastUpdated());
    console.info('Filename: ' + FileName);
    }
  }

  return arrFileIDs;
  console.info('FileIDs Array: ' + arrFileIDs);
};

function DeleteFilesByDate() {
  var arrayIDs = GetFilesByDate();

  for (var i=0; i < arrayIDs.length; i++) {
    console.info('arrayIDs[i]: ' + arrayIDs[i]);
    //This deletes a file without needing to move it to the trash
    var DelResponse = Drive.Files.remove(arrayIDs[i]);
  }
};
```

What i want to accomplish is this. I have files come from google forms upload, i want these file deleted based on date uploaded (7 / 8 days after uploaded etc)

Comment: Can you please add the code you are working on? Don't just rely on an external link, all relevant information should be in the question. Also, explain what do you want to accomplish, what specific issues are you facing, what did you try, etc. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i have added them, TIA.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, some files are getting uploaded to a certain Drive folder every time a Google Form is submitted, and you want to programmatically delete these files after a specific amount of time (7 days, for example). Is this correct?

Comment: yes sir correct

Answer (score 0):

You just need to modify the search query in the script from the article to check the parents property.

```
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('modifiedDate < "' + strCullDate + '" and "' + parentFolderId + '" in parents');
```

where parentFolderId is the Id of the folder, not the name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, let's say my folder is in Root>folder>subfolder>subsubfolder. I just want to remove what's inside of subsubfolder, how to make it works?

Comment: @bidtpirai So you want to remove all files (not folders) from all subfolders (and subsubfolders, etc.) in your main folder?

Comment: @lamblichus i just want to delete all files in a specific folder, sir.

Comment: @bidtpirai Well, do you have the corresponding `folderId`?

Comment: You can get the folder id from the url while browsing drive or by searching by folder name, however the folder name is not unique. There are plenty of resources online to help you implement either solution.

Comment: I find the ID after folders/ ?

Comment: @bidtpirai Yes.

Comment: @bidtpirai I updated my answer so that it only remove files from a specific folder (not subfolders), but I'm still not sure whether that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

## Delete files from a specific folder:

If you just want to delete the files from a specific folder, you can do the following:

- Retrieve the `folderId`. The `ID` of a folder corresponds to the last section of the folder URL, like this:

```
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/{FOLDER_ID}
```

- Modify your search query in order to add `{FOLDER_ID} in parents`:

```
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('modifiedDate < "' + strCullDate + '" and "' + {FOLDER_ID} + '" in parents');
```

**Note**: The `ID` could also be retrieved programmatically if you know the name and this name is unique, using [DriveApp.getFoldersByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfoldersbynamename) (if the name is not unique, you should iterate through the [FolderIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator) in order to find the folder you want):

```
DriveApp.getFoldersByName(name).next();
```

## Delete files from all subfolders:

If you want to delete the files from all subfolders in your main folder, you can do the following:

- Based on the `folderID` of your main folder, use recursion to retrieve all subfolders in this folder (not just immediate children, but also "subsubfolders", etc.). For one example of how to do this, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54912503/).
- Based on the list of folder IDs retrieved in previous step, build the [search query](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms) that you will use for [DriveApp.searchFiles(params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchfilesparams), adding `"PARENT_FOLDER_ID" in parents` for each of the folder IDs, using the [operator `or`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms#operators) if there's more than one folder. Since you have to loop through an array and keep appending to a single output string, using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is a good option, as shown below. I'd recommend adding `title contains ".mp4"` to this query, instead of filtering according to this condition later.

Below is a possible script you can use (I didn't include `DeleteFilesByDate`, since, from what I understood, no modification is required in this function).

#### Code snippet:

```
function GetFilesByDate() {
  const Threshold = new Date().getTime()-3600*1000*24*7;
  const CullDate = new Date(Threshold);
  const strCullDate = Utilities.formatDate(CullDate, "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
  const folderID = "YOUR_FOLDER_ID"; // Add your main folder ID here
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  const folderIDs = recurseFolder(folder, [folderID]);
  const query = getSearchQuery(folderIDs, strCullDate);
  const files = DriveApp.searchFiles(query);
  let fileIDs = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) fileIDs.push(files.next().getId());
  return fileIDs;
};

function getSearchQuery(folderIDs, strCullDate) {
  let query = 'modifiedDate < "' + strCullDate + '" and title contains ".mp4"';
  query = folderIDs.reduce((acc, folderId, i) => {
    if (folderIDs.length === 1) {
      return acc + ' and "' + folderId + '" in parents';
    } else {
      switch (i) {
        case 0:
          return acc + ' and ("' + folderId + '" in parents';
        case folderIDs.length - 1:
          return acc + ' or "' + folderId + '" in parents)';
        default:
          return acc + ' or "' + folderId + '" in parents';
      }
    }
  }, query);
  return query;
}

function recurseFolder(folder, list){
  const subfolders = folder.getFolders();
  while (subfolders.hasNext()){
    const subfolder = subfolders.next();
    list.push(subfolder.getId());
    list = recurseFolder(subfolder, list);
  }
  return list;
}
```

#### Reference:

- [List all files and folder in google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54912503/)
- [Search query terms](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms)